# Unresolved external symbol error, even if function is defined and seen by IDE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, unresolved-external

using Visual C++ 2008, I am having an "Unresolved external symbol" even if with the IDE I can correctly see both declaration and definition of the function:

The error:

```
hook_file.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl is_directory_objattr(struct _OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES const *)" (?is_directory_objattr@@YAHPBU_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES@@@Z)
```

Relevant code in hook_file.cpp:

```
    #include "misc.h"

    void handle_new_file(HANDLE file_handle, const OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES *obj)
        {
            if(is_directory_objattr(obj) == 0 ) { 
            // etc.
```

Declaration in misc.h file:

```
BOOL is_directory_objattr(const OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES *obj);
```

Definition in misc.cpp file:

```
#include "misc.h"

BOOL is_directory_objattr(const OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES *obj)
    { //function body here }
```

I really don't get what the linker has to complain here.

- The header with function declaration is included by the file which
  calls the function.
- The cpp file with the function definition included header file with declaration.
- Declaration and definitions are identical.
- All files are listed among project files.

Any idea whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a link error, not a compilation error. Check that your projects are linked to whatever libraries they need to.

Comment: Check your linker settings.

Comment: There are no external libraries needed, the function which generates the error is coded  in my project as you can read on my question.
Linker settings does not have anything wrong.
Its like if the IDE can see the function definition in the cpp file, but the linker doesn't.

Comment: From what you gave, it looks ok. Are you sure the linker is getting `misc.obj`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you only include one time your header file?

in misc.h

```
#ifndef MISC
#define MISC

...

#endif MISC ?
```